# ArcObjects: Getting the properties of a layer that has lost its data source (VB.NET)

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, alias

When you save an ArcGIS map document (MXD) and then change the data source of a layer in the MXD, you can no longer see the layer in the MXD and you must redefine its data source.

But suppose you need to discover the previous data source's feature class name. In ArcMap, you can find it under the layer's Properties -> Source Tab, but I want to access this information programmatically.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work for this kind of layer. Can anyone suggest another method for retrieving the properties of a layer whose data source has been lost?

```vb
ctype(mLayer,IFeatureLayer).aliasname
```

Comment: This will fail as the source doesn't exist. Try using a property dialog...and retrieve the value from there. Refer [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FeatureLayerSourcePropertyPageClass_Class/00130000003t000000/) and this [forum link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=103935)

Answer (score 7):

If the layer implements the [IDataLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDataLayer_Interface/00120000037v000000/) interface (most layers do), you can access its [IDataLayer.DataSourceName](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DataSourceName_Property/001200000389000000/) property.

For example, for a feature layer, this property will return the [FeatureClassName](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IName_Interface/00420000014r000000/) object, which provides various interfaces to examine the data source.

Answer (score 1):

This will fail as the source doesn't exist.
Try using a property dialog...and retrieve the value from there. Refer [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FeatureLayerSourcePropertyPageClass_Class/00130000003t000000/) and this [forum link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=103935)